# PhP mail program changes my Apostrophe(') turns into â€™

Tags: php

When I send email through PHP mail program my apostrophe beocomes â€™.

Why is this happening ?
How can It be corrected ?

Should read (Tutor's) , but instead it reads (Tutorâ€™s)

Comment: Are you sure its `Tutor's` and not `Tutor’s`? if the latter then your client is reading your utf-8 data as latin-1.

Answer (score 0):

copy paste your code

look at your page charset UTF-8?
and open your page file-save as and save UTF-8 formated

and look at your replace function...

I'm sorry my english...